# Resize (proportionally) an image when placing XML using XSLT on to InDesign CS5, IF image is >200px wide

Tags: xslt, adobe-indesign

Any/all help appreciated, thanks!

Currently the code in XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:if test="logo[.!='']">
   <logo>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">file://logos/<xsl:value-of select="logo"/></xsl:attribute>
   </logo>
   <xsl:text></xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

**Update from comments**

> Desired result is to get XSLT to
>   resize/downsize images, then place
>   them in InDesign CS5 across columns
>   (think membership directory with each
>   member having a picture pf various
>   dimensions, but in the final InDesign
>   output we want them to appear no
>   bigger than 200 px wide). I guess the
>   question is, is there any way XSLT can
>   'sense' that a jpg is bigger than 200
>   px wide, and using a conditional
>   statement, actually proportionately
>   size it down to 200 px and dynamically
>   place in InDesign CS5? The XML file
>   doesn't come with the image height and
>   width info

Comment: So, what is the XML document (the minimal possible, please), and what is the desired result?

Comment: Desired result is to get XSLT to resize/downsize images, then place them in InDesign CS5 across columns (think membership directory with each member having a picture pf various dimensions, but in the final InDesign output we want them to appear no bigger than 200 px wide). I guess the question is, is there any way XSLT can 'sense' that a jpg is bigger than 200 px wide, and using a conditional statement, actually proportionately size it down to 200 px and dynamically place in InDesign CS5? The XML file doesn't come with the image height and width info.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT doesn't have a built-in library for performing operations on images. You'll have to create one using whatever capabilities your chosen XSLT processor provides for defining extension functions.